# Groovy remove space indexes from array

Tags: arrays, groovy

headers is an array that is populated from a file.  When I print headers, I get:

```
headers = ["The Year", , , "The Make", "The Model"]
```

I'm trying to use `headers.remove(' ')` to get rid of those two cells that are just spaces.  It will not run or compile with that syntax, and I cannot find what I am doing wrong.  I have tested:

```
def list1 = ['j', 2, 3, 4]

list1.remove('j')
```

And it works just fine.  I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use def headers = ["The Year","" ,"" , "The Make", "The Model"]

Comment: I should've explained. headers is actually being returned from somewhere else, and it may contain blank entries like I showed above.

Comment: I doubt that considering "def headers = ["The Year", , , "The Make", "The Model"] " doesn't compile. It's an illegal expression

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `["The Year", , , "The Make", "The Model"]` is actually the toString representation of the list

```
groovy:000> ["The Year", , , "The Make", "The Model"]
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
startup failed:
groovysh_parse: 1: unexpected token: , @ line 1, column 14.
   ["The Year", , , "The Make", "The Model"]
            ^
groovy:000> ['"The Year"', '', '', '"The Make"', '"The Model"']
===> ["The Year", , , "The Make", "The Model"]
```

I think `headers.remove(' ')` isn't working because the elements aren't actually spaces, they're empty. I'm not sure why `headers.remove('')` wouldn't work, except that you'd need to use `headers.removeAll('')`.

A better option would be to use something like `headers.findAll { it.trim() != '' }`.

Comment: `headers = lines[0].split(',')`      is where headers gets populated

`println headers[0]`  successfully returns "The Year" 

removeAll did not work, for ' ' or ''.

Comment: If you're parsing a CSV, I'd recommend trying [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).